# Validating a form from jquery plugin. bassistance.de

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

i want to validate my form with the script written below. I tried, but it doesnt validates.. Below is my code. any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<form id="signupForm">
        <table id="control_Table">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                    <label for="fullname">
                        Full Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                    <label for="email">
                        Email Address</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                    <label for="username">
                        User Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtuname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                    <label for="password">
                        Password</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                    <label for="confirm_password">
                        Confirm Password
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                    Active User
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                    Admin User
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdmin" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

This below is the script to the form.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            fullname: "required",
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#MainContent_txtPwd"
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            fullname: "Please enter your firstname",
            username: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        }
    });

    // propose username by combining first- and lastname
    $("#MainContent_txtuname").focus(function() {
        var firstname = $("#MainContent_txtfullname").val();
        var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
        if (firstname && lastname && !this.value) {}
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You must provide `name` attributes for your inputs in addition to `id` attributes.  The Validate plugin and all your rules have to refer to `name` not `id`.

From the documentation on the `rules` option for [validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):

> Key/value pairs defining custom rules. Key is the **name** of an element
>   (or a group of checkboxes/radio buttons), value is an object
>   consisting of rule/parameter pairs or a plain String.... [it continues]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your IDs.. Server control ID doesn't match resulting element ID in ASP.NET by default.

You could use `ClientIDMode="Static"` if you are on .NET framework 4.0 or newer, or just make sure you reference correct element IDs in your scripts.

See ClientIDMode Enumeration with descriptions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx).

Comment: yeah, using framework 4.. thanks for the suggestion brother. i`l definitely work upon it.